# Is it possible to make forever loops in Xcode without making Xcode freeze?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been trying to make a clicker game with Xcode, and I have run into a problem. I want to make a button that gives you some clicks (the currency in the game) every second. The only way I know how to do this is if I use

```
while true { 
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1),   execute: {
     self.clicks += self.helpers
     self.ClickLable.text = "Clicks: \(self.clicks)"
     print(self.clicks)
     }
   })
}
```

, but the `while true{}` would cause Xcode to freeze. Is there other way to do this?

Comment: @GurunathSripad this is exactly what a `Timer` is for. Recursion is not meant to be used infinitely, since you will hit the stack depth limit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Timer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer) class.

The timer will call the following block every `TimeInterval`.

You can intialize a timer like this:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
  self.clicks += self.helpers
  self.ClickLable.text = "Clicks: \(self.clicks)"
  print(self.clicks)
}
```